# Ignoring to Select text on inherited RichTextbox?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, richtextbox, overriding

In my usercontrol I want to prevent the user to select text, I mean I want to cancel (ignore) all the mouse events, I've overrided the important events but seems does nothing 'cause I'm still be able to select text on the control.

PS: Is not an option for me to Disable the control to prevent selection, I want to disable selection.

```
Public Class RichTextLabel : Inherits RichTextBox

    Private Declare Function HideCaret Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        Me.TabStop = False
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        Me.Size = New Point(200, 20)
        Me.ReadOnly = True
        Me.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
        Me.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None
    End Sub

    Public Sub Add_Colored_Text(ByVal text As String, _
                                ByVal color As Color, _
                                Optional ByVal font As Font = Nothing)

        Dim index As Int32 = Me.TextLength
        Me.AppendText(text)
        Me.SelectionStart = index
        Me.SelectionLength = Me.TextLength - index
        Me.SelectionColor = color
        If font IsNot Nothing Then Me.SelectionFont = font
        Me.SelectionLength = 0

    End Sub

#Region " Overrided Events "

    Protected Overrides Sub OnClick(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        HideCaret(Me.Handle)
        Return
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnSelectionChanged(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        HideCaret(Me.Handle)
        Return
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseClick(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
        HideCaret(Me.Handle)
        ' MyBase.OnClick(e)
        Return
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDoubleClick(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
        HideCaret(Me.Handle)
        Return
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
        HideCaret(Me.Handle)
        Return
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseUp(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
        HideCaret(Me.Handle)
        Return
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Handled Events "

    Private Sub On_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseHover
        HideCaret(Me.Handle)
    End Sub

    Private Sub On_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.TextChanged
        HideCaret(Me.Handle)
    End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

Comment: Why can't you disable the control? Is it only because it turns the text grey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a hack, but at least it is a clean one:

- Add an element to the class that can have focus
- Have `HideSelection = True` (Set to `True` by default, but just be aware not to change it)
- Override the `OnEnter` event to pass focus to the child control

This way, the RichTextBox never holds onto the focus, so even if it does have selected text it wont show to the user.

---

```
Public Class RichTextLabel : Inherits RichTextBox

    Private controlToTakeFocus As New Label() With {
        .Width = 0,
        .Height = 0,
        .Text = String.Empty}

    Public Sub New()
        ' Default value is True, but is required for this solution
        'Me.HideSelection = True
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(e As MouseEventArgs)
        Me.Parent.Controls.Add(controlToTakeFocus)
        controlToTakeFocus.Focus()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Edit: The control `controlToTakeFocus` needs to be able to take focus, which it can't until it is on the `Form`. I changed the overridden event to `OnMouseDown` and added a line to add the control to the `RichTextLabel`'s Parent before trying to give it focus. There is probably a better place for this, but this is just to get it working.

Comment: Thanks but is not working for me, copied your code and pasted it as is, also I've tried to override the mouse events and then call "controlToTakeFocus.focus", but nothing, I still can select text on the control, I've tested it with FW4.0 in a Winforms.